# How should I format backup media for space efficiency?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, disk-space, storage

In my working environment based on Linux, we use some 2-8TB disks for backup storage. Most files are around 50-500MB. Each file is written once, and rarely read. The writing is not frequent. In this case, we care about the space efficiency more than I/O performance.

I was using ext3/4, but I found that the space efficiency of ext3/4 is not so good. About 10% of the space is used by the metadata of the file system itself. Thus, I want to switch to a file system with better space efficiency. Which file system is the best choice for my situation?

Comment: With a little refining this could be a better question - what are the hard requirements, so that that given files can be tested, and actual size results compared? Have to be read-write, or read-only, or must work on Windows/Mac/Linux, etc? It's not an *opinion* if one is smaller than another...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're basically doing "write-once" style backups, you could skip a regular filesystem and use compression, either a large archive, or a compressed filesystem like **squashfs**

[SquashFS HOWTO - 4. Creating and using squashed file systems](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/creatingandusing.html)

> In order to create a squashed file system out of a single directory (say, /some/dir), and output it to a regular file (thus, producing a file system image), you need to say only one magic phrase:
>
> ```
>   bash# mksquashfs /some/dir dir.sqsh
> ```

It can use some different compression algorithms too, gzip is very fast & super for text, while xz is slower but compresses very well. From `man mksquashfs`:

> -comp **COMPRESSION**
>      select **COMPRESSION** compression. Compressors available: gzip (default), lzo, xz.

You can even use unionfs (or overlayfs) to make it "writeable" - See the SquashFS HOWTO link above.

Answer (score 1):

There could possibly other suggestions but a robust solution that takes less space for META data is XFS.